# Black Body emission - Coupling of $E$ and $B$ field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, thermal-radiation, electromagnetic-induction

I do not understand how a black body emits electromagnetic radiation. I assume that heating a black body creates moving charges which induce a magnetic field. But where is the $E$ field part of the electromagnetic radiation coming from? For the $B$ Field to induce an electric field it would have to vary in strength? It would be great if someone could please clear that up for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A charge just has an E-field contribution, extending out to infinity, in classical electromagnetism. If you are not seeing it, that is not because it does not exist, it is probably because it is being canceled out by similar contributions from another charge. Since the equations are linear, they obey superposition, and so the two static fields can destructively interfere. The simplest examples are dipole fields, which aren't zero but do go to zero like $1/r^3$ which is faster than a radiation amplitude’s $1/r$ or a static field’s $1/r^2$.

Now, if you have two charges that oscillate, for example, each of them can be treated under the auspices of linearity as producing its own separate electromagnetic radiation. That radiation can destructively interfere sometimes, but it requires a lot of setup. In particular, two identical point sources of monochromatic light cannot be made to cancel out over all of space if they're not at the exact same origin; instead you get a interference pattern across space where some lines have zero intensity and the other lines have greater intensity. And if the charges aren't oscillating at the exact same frequency, then you don't really get cancellation anywhere, you get a superposition of two different colors of light.

In this sense, radiation is harder to destructively cancel than stationary fields. You often still get things propagating out to infinity like $1/r$ even when you contrive things, like using two or three radio antennas and perfectly adjust the phase offsets to get better coverage of a distant metro area by constructive interference at the expense of some of the countryside.

Of course in blackbody radiation, all of these charges whose fields cancel are bumping around randomly and accelerating that way: so they still emit radiation as they accelerate, but they are in absolutely no sort of order to cancel that radiation over any sort of long range.

Comment: thanks! Sry for the time delay but i had to think about this topic really hard! Your last paragraph especially describes the solution very well

Answer (score 0):

The E and B part come from charged particles. The E part of Electromagnetic black body radiation is the charges moving in response with other charges and for the M part of Electromagnetic moving charges create magnetic field which results in the EM(Electromagnetic) wave.

Comment: Thank you. But what do you mean with  that the E part is due to the charges moving in response with other charges? I am not a native english speaker so maybe i dont understand correctly. I thought that i would need an imbalance of charges to create an e field or a time dependant b field

Comment: It is because two charges are moving in response with one another. It has to be two or more because if it is only one then conservation of momentum would be violated.

Comment: so you mean that the charges interact with each other (e.g. collide) and thus each is changing its direction and speed (Energy). So a lot of small B-fields are changing always and thus induce a E-field?

Comment: Well that too, but also sometimes the charges do not exactly cancel. They almost perfectly cancel but the key word here is almost. So this results in electromagnetic radiation.

Answer (score 0):

To start with , [black body radiation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html) is one of the main reasons quantum mechanics was invented , so that  the shape of the  radiation could be fitted.

> The amount of radiation emitted in a given frequency range should be proportional to the number of modes in that range. The best of classical physics suggested that all modes had an equal chance of being produced, and that the number of modes went up proportional to the square of the frequency.

Classical E and B field calculations led to the [ultraviolet catastrophy](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html#c4) in the calculated spectrum, and the data did not show such a behavior, the behavior can be explained in the quantum frame.

Planck's assumption of quantized energy  fitted the experimental curves.

[image: black body]

We now know that matter consists of atoms and molecules, and the electrons are bound in specific energy levels that can be excited when they scatter against each other in a gas, and deexcited by releasing photons , due to the kinetic energy. In liquids and solids there are  rotational and vibrational energy levels , extra degrees of freedom.

See also this for the [radiated energy.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/stefan.html)